# Javascript not executing reliably – RoR4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an issue where I use javascript to check all/uncheck all tick boxes, however it I navigate to a page from another URL, it won't submit the form. When I refresh the page, or type the URL in directly, it will work. I thought this might be a turbolinks issue, however I'm not having a problem with any other javascript on the site. I am loading the JS at the end of the page, after everything else has loaded.

My code is as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");
    if(checkboxes.prop("checked")){
        document.getElementById("check_all").innerHTML = "Deselect All";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("check_all").innerHTML = "Select All";
    }
   $('#check_all').on("click", function() {
    if(checkboxes.prop("checked")){
        checkboxes.prop("checked",false);
        document.getElementById("check_all").innerHTML = "Select All";
    }
    else {
        checkboxes.prop("checked",true);
        document.getElementById("check_all").innerHTML = "Deselect All";
    }
  });
});
```

I'm using Rails 4, I do get an error sometimes which is as follows:
*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null*

Comment: Make sure your JS script element is at the bottom of the page, or the code is inside an onload event. Otherwise the element you're targeting may not exist when the code executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely to be a Turbolinks issue.

Your code inside the handler for the `$(document).ready` event which fires when the page has loaded enough to do JS operations on the DOM. This is normally the right practice for this sort of thing, but with Turbolinks it's different.

Turbolinks intercepts link clicks and instead of reloading the page it makes an AJAX request for the body of the desired page and swaps it in for the body of the current page. This makes the `$(document).ready` event unreliable - it might not get fired. So instead Turbolinks fires an event when it change the page content: `page:change`

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

use

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
```